# Animate progress bar on clicking a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to animate the progress bar after clicking on a link. Here is the HTML :

```
<a class="link" href="#">Click Me</a>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="meter meter1"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="meter meter2"></div>
</div>
```

And the attached CSS :

```
.progress{
        width: 300px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #c4c4c4;
    }

    .meter{
        height: 20px;
        background: #000;
        width: 0%;
    }
```

The jQuery code I've written is as follow :

```
        $.('.link').click(function(){

        $('.meter1').animate({width:'80%'}, 3000, 'swing');
        $('.meter2').animate({width:'70%'}, 3000, 'swing');

    });
```

Though if I remove the click event and simply load the page, the animations are working. How I can made them animate after clicking the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a `.` in front of the click function

```
$.('.link')
```

should be

```
$('.link')
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/N7EZ4/1/)

Comment: You beat me to it by *one* second! :(

Comment: What a silly mistake...now I got to know the side effects of working without sleeping. Really need to sleep. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it happens, i know all about that haha